# PHP convert HTML to docx

Tags: php, html, ms-word, docx, doc

I have an issue: I have to convert HTML file to docx, the important thing is that i have large html file so PhpOffice\PhpWord does not help.

Also I have a second option: I have docx file but i have to change something in there. I tried this:

```
$templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor('ref2.docx');
$templateProcessor->setValue(['{{name}}', '{{spec}}', '{{email}}'], [$array[0], $array[1], $array[2]]);
$templateProcessor->saveAs($array[0].'_WORD.docx');
```

but it didn't work (it worked for the first parameter, but the last one..)

What should i do to make it work correctly?

Comment: is `setValues` not `setValue` for array.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates-processing.html), PHPWord can handle big files.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple values replacement, by referring to the [documentation](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates-processing.html#setvalues), try replace your code with the correct function and syntax

From

```
$templateProcessor->setValue(['{{name}}', '{{spec}}', '{{email}}'], [$array[0], $array[1], $array[2]]);
```

To

```
$templateProcessor->setValues([
  '{{name}}'  => $array[0], 
  '{{spec}}'  => $array[1], 
  '{{email}}' => $array[2]
]);
```

Hope it helps!